# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un input type text o text area con etiquetas HTML en una app .NET Blazor server-side?

Tags: html, c#, .net, blazor

¿Cómo puedo enviar un input type text o text area con etiquetas **HTML** utilizando **.NET Blazor server-side**?

Cuando envío un input de tipo texto sin etiquetas **HTML**, la información enviada entra perfectamente, pero cuando incluyo algunas etiquetas **HTML** en el input, el texto enviado viene vacío, **¿cómo puedo enviar inputs con etiquetas HTML?**

Aquí está mi código **HTML**:

```
<input type="text"
id="quill-result-body"
class="form-control"
required
@bind="BlogPost!.Body" /><input type="text"
id="quill-result-body"
class="form-control"
required
@bind="BlogPost!.Body" />
```

Como mencioné, si el input no tiene etiquetas **HTML**, la información enviada ubicada en **BlogPost.Body** viene perfecta, pero cuando pongo algunas etiquetas **HTML**, viene vacía.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Creé un proyecto de ejemplo de Blazor server, agregué un textarea y un endpoint que recibe un string. Escribí código html en el textarea y lo envíe al endpoint, el cual lo leyó sin problemas